# In Catia Moving Parts or Products with Macro

Tags: vba, catia

I try to move selected parts or products with Vb macro. First one should go -5 mm on Y-axis and the second one should go +5mm on Y-Axis can you help me guys?

I tried to choose move selected Products with function of Move but I cant.

```vb
Sub Kaydir()
    Dim Selection As Selection
    Set Selection = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection
    Dim product As Product
    Set product = Selection.Item(1).Value
    
    ' Y ekseni boyunca 5mm kaydırma
    Dim YDistance As Double
    YDistance = 5 ' Kaydırma mesafesi (mm)
    
    ' Yönünü belirtmek için oluşturulan Vector
    Dim Vector(8) As Double
    Vector(0) = 0
    Vector(1) = YDistance
    Vector(2) = 0
    
    ' Ürünün mevcut pozisyonunu almak
    Dim currentPosition(11) As Double
    currentPosition = product.GetPosition
    
    ' Yeni pozisyonu hesaplamak
    Dim newPosition(11) As Double
    For i = 0 To 5
        newPosition(i) = currentPosition(i) + Vector(i)
    Next i
    
    ' Yeni pozisyonu ayarlamak
    product.Move newPosition
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share your code you tried and explain where you run into troubles.

Comment: I share the code can you help me

Comment: Try `product.SetComponents newPosition` instead of the move operation. The last three elements of the currentPosition/newPosition array are the coordinates, so you have to modify your calculation.

Comment: Just it is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim oProd As Product
Set oProd = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection.Item(1).Value

Dim oMove As Move
Set oMove = oProd.Move

'variant array for the transformation matrix, last 3 are the translation
Dim xform(11)
xform(0) = 1#
xform(1) = 0#
xform(2) = 0#
xform(3) = 0#
xform(4) = 1#
xform(5) = 0#
xform(6) = 0#
xform(7) = 0#
xform(8) = 1#
xform(9) = 0#
xform(10) = 5#
xform(11) = 0#

'VBA: because you are passing an array, a variant object is required
Dim vMove As Variant
Set vMove = oMove
Call vMove.Apply(xform)
```